# Why can't I get textbox.text values from code generated textboxes

Tags: vba, textbox

I have a project where I have a form "userform1" which only has a "GO" button and an "EXIT" button on it to begin with. I solicit user input via an inputbox for a number. I use code to then populate the form with that number of labels and textboxes and display the form to allow editting of the created textboxes. Everything works fine up to this point.
I then want the "GO" button to populate an array with the textbox.text values for use elsewhere. This is where I am having a problem.

I tried retrieving the text like I normally do (something like; Xstring = UserForm1.Box1.Text), that didn't work. So then I cycled thru the form controls; UserForm1.Controls.index(), looking for my Textbox .names to confirm they existed. I found them, so I singled one out, index(3), .name = "Box1".  See below:

```
Dim tText As String
tText = UserForm1.Box1.Text
MsgBox tText
```

returns an ERROR, 'method or data member not found'

But if I change it to this:

```
Dim x As Object
Dim tText As String
Set x = UserForm1.Controls.Item(3)
tText = x.Text
MsgBox tText
```

The msgbox returns the .text value

So, QUESTION is, why can't I simply address it normally? I don't want to have to go through all the extra steps to figure out index numbers vs names to populate my array.

for reference, below is partial code of my sub for creating labels/textboxes:

```
For i = Data(x, 1) To z
    Lab = "forms.label.1"
    Box = "forms.textbox.1"
    Set newlabel = UserForm1.Controls.Add(Lab)
    Set newtextbox = UserForm1.Controls.Add(Box)
    lbl1 = ("Label" + CStr(i))
    With newlabel
        .Name = lbl1
        .Caption = "No. " + CStr(i)
        .Left = Data(x, 3)
        .top = top
        .Height = 20
        .Width = 30
    End With
    lbl2 = ("Box" + CStr(i))
    With newtextbox
        .Name = lbl2
        .Text = CStr(i)
        .Left = (Data(x, 3) + 35)
        .top = top
        .Height = 20
        .Width = 36
    End With
    top = top + 25
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

`UserForm1` has no method or data member of that name before run-time. Therefore the VBA interpreter cannot interpret what is meant.

You can nevertheless access the item via through its collection of child controls indexed on either index number or control name, like:

```
Dim myTxtBox As MSForms.TextBox

Me.Controls.Add bstrProgId:="Forms.Textbox.1", Name:="My Runtime Textbox"

Set myTxtBox = Me.Controls("My Runtime Textbox")

myTxtBox.Text = "Hello"
```

Comment: I reworked my textbox creation per your suggestion. It did not seem to make a difference in that, 'userfom1.textbox1.text' still does not yield any result. It didn't hurt either...

Comment: @HarryToes `userfom1.textbox1.text` will never work unless `textbox1` was created at design time (I.e. you drag a textbox onto the form and give it a name "textbox1". You have to index the form's child controls as demonstrated. It looks like youa re trying to find all the textboxes. INstead of 'guessing' based on the name of the control, test the object type of the control like `for each cntrl in Me.Controls: if typeof cntrl is TextBox then: 'do some stuff: end if: next`

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments from Cor_Blimey, this is what I now have working in the code for retrieving my program generated textbox.text data:

```
Dim i As Integer, num As Integer, ctr As Integer
Dim oCntl As Object
Dim tText() as String

num = UserForm1.Controls.Count
ReDim tText(num)
For Each Control In UserForm1.Controls 'loops thru each control
    If TypeOf Control Is TextBox Then
        ctr = ctr + 1
        tText(ctr) = Control.Text
    End If
Next Control
ReDim Preserve tText(ctr)
```

The .text is being written to the array sequentially (by index#, the order textboxes were created)
In the future, I might consider 2 values in the array, 1 for .name and 1 for .text, just to be sure.